# Boolean operation on Prometheus label

Tags: prometheus, grafana

In Grafana, stat panel I'd like to display if a service is up or down for the following metrics below,

```
service_status{id="wl4r67mtj2y8",name="APIs",service="test",status="operational"} 1
service_status{id="wl4r67mtj2y8",name="APIs",service="test",status="not operational"} 1
```

But part of the problem is that the gauge value is ofcourse static. So the only option is to look at the `status` label.

**Background**: This is a result of using the [json-exporter](https://github.com/prometheus-community/json_exporter) which lacks in features but what I have available right now to parse a JSON file.

```
metrics:
- name: test
  type: object
  help: Saltedge component statuses
  # path: $.page
  path: $.components[*]?(@.id == "wl4r67mtj2y8")
  labels:
    service: test
    id: $.id
    name: $.name
    status: $.status
  values:
    status: 1
```

Any way to achieve this in a prometheus query or Grafana ? That is to query based on `status` field and use in value mappings in Grafana stat panel ?